Prove or disprove this statement about invertible Hessians?
Prove or disprove: Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a twice-continuously differentiable function. Suppose $\nabla^2f(x)$, the Hessian of $f$ is invertible. Then there exists some $r>0$ such that $\|\nabla^2f(y)^{-1}\|_2\leq 2\|\nabla^2 f(x)^{-1}\|$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfies $\|x-y\|_2\leq r$.
I am relatively new with multivariable analysis. However, I can prove the claim true in 1D, which is equivalent to saying there exists some $r>0$ such that $|f''(y)|\geq |f''(x)|/2$, which is immediately obvious from continuity of $f''$ (use $\varepsilon = |f''(x)|/2$). However, I do not know how to extend this to matrices.
Another question is whether there are some nice books that give all these properties of Hessians and gradients in n dimensions. Most of the multivariable analysis books I could find don't really cover the properties of these objects nicely.

Hint for one possible way. Hessian is symmetric so you can choose an orthonormal basis which diagonalizes it and then you have the eigenvalues on the diagonal. Then you you just have to look at either the smallest or largest one by magnitude (but I can't be bothered to check which one is the correct one here).

The mapping $A \mapsto A^{-1}$ is continuous and so is the matrix norm (all norms are continuous). The claim follows by continuity.
To see that $A\mapsto A^{-1}$ is continuous, recall that $A^{-1} = \mathrm{Adj}(A)/\det A$, which is continuous because determinants are continuous.
